# Does using razor in WebMatrix mitigate an XSS threat?

Tags: c#, razor, xss, webmatrix, html-encode

I have purposfully (for testing) assigned the following variable in WebMatrix C#:

```
string val = "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('XSS Vector')</script>";
```

Later in the page I have used razor to write that value directly to the page.

```
<p>
    @val
</p>
```

It writes the text, but in a safe manner (i.e., no alert scripts run)

This, coupled with the fact that if 'val' contains an html entity (e.g., `&lt;`) it also writes exactly "`&lt;`" and not "<" as I would expect the page to render.

Is this because C# runs first, then html is rendered?

More importantly, is using razor in this fashion a suitable replacement for html encoding, when used like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Variable` syntax will HtmlEncode any text you pass to it; hence you seeing literally what you set to the string value. You are correct in that this is for XSS protection. It is part of Razor that does this; the `@Variable` syntax itself.

So basically, using the `@Variable` syntax is not so much a 'replacement' for Html Encoding; it *is* HTML encoding.

Related: If you ever want some string to *render* the HTML, you would use this syntax in Razor:

```
@Html.Raw(Variable)
```

That causes the Html Encoding *not* to be done. Obviously, this is dangerous to do with user-supplied input.

Comment: Nice! Thank you, so much! This coupled with the fact that Request["someVar"] (for a querystring) automatically UrlDecodes is really making my job easier! Call me a nOOb (cause compared to others on this site, I am), but I love WebMatrix! It's everything my little web designing heart desires, all in a centralized application.

Comment: Also, thanks for showing me @Html.Raw(). I will (however, cautiously) remember that it is there in case I need to write data in a more old-fashioned way.

Comment: @VoidKing Maybe you're a noob, but you asked a decent question. Glad I could help!

Comment: Well, I certainly appreciate it!